# What kind of RAM should I use for my iMac?

Tags: memory

My Specs are as follows:

Model Name:    iMac
  Model Identifier: iMac10,1
  Processor Name:   Intel Core 2 Duo
  Processor Speed:  3.06 GHz
  Number Of Processors: 1
  Total Number Of Cores:    2
  L2 Cache: 3 MB
  Memory:   4 GB
  Bus Speed:    1.07 GHz
  Boot ROM Version: IM101.00CC.B00
  SMC Version (system): 1.52f9
  Serial Number (system):   W8008JEF5PC
  Hardware UUID:    EECDACBD-AF6B-5B3E-B382-2702F2AA64AD

Current RAM:
Memory Slots:

ECC:  Disabled

BANK 0/DIMM0:

Size: Empty
  Type: Empty
  Speed:    Empty
  Status:   Empty
  Manufacturer: Empty
  Part Number:  Empty
  Serial Number:    Empty

BANK 1/DIMM0:

Size: Empty
  Type: Empty
  Speed:    Empty
  Status:   Empty
  Manufacturer: Empty
  Part Number:  Empty
  Serial Number:    Empty

BANK 0/DIMM1:

Size: 2 GB
  Type: DDR3
  Speed:    1067 MHz
  Status:   OK
  Manufacturer: 0x80AD
  Part Number:  0x484D54313235533642465238432D47372020
  Serial Number:    0x108343E7

BANK 1/DIMM1:

Size: 2 GB
  Type: DDR3
  Speed:    1067 MHz
  Status:   OK
  Manufacturer: 0x80AD
  Part Number:  0x484D54313235533642465238432D47372020
  Serial Number:    0x101343E9

1. What sort/kind of RAM should I purchase to improve the current RAM capacity?
2. Should I buy an extra 2 x 2GB RAM or 2 x 4GB?
3. Which Slot should it be inserted to should I purchase the new RAMs?
4. Will it have a negative effect on the overall performance?

Answer (score 3):

Getting a performance boost depends on what you actually do with the thing.  Run Activity-Monitor (Applications>Utilities) to see how much of your RAM is used.  Most Mac stuff runs well on 4GB, but if you run memory intense stuff (Parallels-Windows, Video Editing, editing large pictures with photoshop) you should see an improvement.  But even if you don't need the RAM, you should not see a performance penalty (i.e. it may or may not run better, but won't run worse).

Unless your computer is already slowing down to a crawl with the current configuration (when doing memory intense work), adding 2x 2GB should be enough (giving you a total of 8GB).

So, given your configuration, I'd add 2x 2GB to the free slots and keep the memory that is already there in the other slot.

Comment: but if I know manufacturer, what cards should I install? My manufacturer is `0x80AD` (Macbook Pro Late 2011)

Answer (score 2):

Apple has a bunch of [support articles](http://support.apple.com/kb/index?page=search&src=support_site.home.search&locale=en_US&q=adding%20ram%20to%20imac) on their Support site, just pick the one which applies to your model.

Answer (score 1):

I second Patrix's answer.

As for the overall performance impact, as long as you install the correct type of RAM in duals (meaning 2 sticks of the same type), it should boost your performance.

You need to pay attention to how much RAM your iMac model takes as maximum. You already have 4GB; check if it's possible for you to replace both sticks to 2x4GB for a total of 8GB.

Update based on the comment below:

This [article](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3918) lists the steps necessary to add/change RAM for your iMac model. Your iMac model (Late 2009) contains 4 RAM slots; each slot can hold 4 GB maximum for a total of 16 GB RAM. The RAM type is SO-DIMMs **1066 MHz DDR3** SDRAM. Here is an example from [Newegg.com](http://www.newegg.com/Product/ProductList.aspx?Submit=ENE&N=100007968%20600032324%20600032360&IsNodeId=1&name=DDR3%201066%20%28PC3%208500%29).

Comment: 21.5" Screen                                            NVIDIA GeForce 9400:

  Chipset Model: NVIDIA GeForce 9400
  Type: GPU
  Bus: PCI
  VRAM (Total): 256 MB
  Vendor: NVIDIA (0x10de)
  Device ID: 0x0869
  Revision ID: 0x00b1
  ROM Revision: 3454
  Displays:
iMac:
  Resolution: 1920 x 1080
  Pixel Depth: 32-Bit Color (ARGB8888)
  Main Display: Yes
  Mirror: Off
  Online: Yes
  Built-In: Yes
Display Connector:
  Status: No Display Connected

Comment: Check the update to my answer above.